# Only specific dynamodb table throwing ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-dynamodb

This is weird, I have a lambda called dispatcher that calls multiple lambdas in parallel and awaits them. Which single lambda that gets fired reads data from a dynamodb table.

I have logic in place to wait 3 seconds and try again the read from the dynamo table, but still is not enough and the lambda times out because of multiple ProvisionedThroughputExceededException.

But the lambda timing out (even with retries) is always the lambda responsible for reading from the same specific table, lets call it table_that_blows.

I was checking the configurations for this table and it's on provisioning mode like the other tables.

Is it because all the tables are on the same region? EU-West? Does the reads from a specific table affect the reads of another table in the same region?

What is happening? I have tables with more data than the table_that_blows and still, the error occurs always on the same table.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the particular read action is using more than the available read credits. If you're using a scan on a large table that will very quickly deplete available credits.

Comment: I have larger tables and the scaling is working properly for those, why on this specific table the scaling is not working as it should? Also the read action is the same across all the tables.

Comment: Is it possible a specific attribute has large data in it? If you have a look at the metrics for the DynamoDB table try looking at ReturnedItemCount and ReturnedItemCount based metrics to see if you can notice any differences between the tables

Comment: I checked the Query returned item count and in fact that table_that_blows has huge spikes on it of 3500 of value, while my larger table has only values of 2000.